# DotNetZip (Ionic.Zip.dll) doesn't work with compress Chinese File or Folder name

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

It is very perfect condition  when I use as following code to compress English file or folder name,However I do have got serious problem when the name change **from English to Chinese name** , it isn't work.
How can i do ????

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
   zip.AddDirectory(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\a");  // Zip folder included all branch files
   zip.Save(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Projectzip.zip");//location and name for creating zip file
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found answer to deal with my problem

> using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(System.Text.Encoding.Default))

thanks